# error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1 while installing appscript

Tags: python

```
In file included from appscript_3x/ext/ae.c:15:0:
    appscript_3x/ext/ae.h:26:27: fatal error: Carbon/Carbon.h: No such file or directory
     #include <Carbon/Carbon.h>
                               ^
    compilation terminated.
    error: command 'x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit status 1

Command "/usr/bin/python3 -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-3szl1iid/appscript/setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-b5m_q0x6-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-3szl1iid/appscript
```

Getting this error when I try and install the "appscript" module for Python via sudo pip install.  Usually I can read the error messages to get a better idea of what went wrong, but I have no idea this time.  Can any of you help me?  Thanks!

Comment: IMO I had long time ago similar error when installing on linux a package that was for IOS

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka that appears to be my problem too - thank you!